# Use of dynamic-insert and dynamic-update

Tags: hibernate

Can you explain me what is the use of dynamic-insert and dynamic-update attributes in a class mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They simply tell Hibernate whether to include unmodified properties in SQL INSERT and SQL UPDATE.